# Can't save custom address attribute

Tags: magento2

I've created a new customer address attribute called 'landline' (required). I've used the code generated by https://mage2gen.com/ which seems 'correct' to me:

- Attribute is correctly created and displayed
- I can save the attribute from the backoffice

However, if I try to create a new address programmatically and set a value for this new attribute, I get the following error:

```
"Landline" is a required value.
```

If I create the attribute but it's not required, then the address is generated, but the landline field is empty.

This is the code I use for address generation:

```
$address = $this->customerAddressFactory->create();

$address->setCustomerId($customerId)
                ->setFirstname($addressData['firstname'])
                ->setLastname($addressData['lastname'])
                ->setCountryId($addressData['country_id'])
                ->setRegionId($addressData['region_id'])
                ->setPostcode($addressData['postcode'])
                ->setCity($addressData['city'])
                ->setTelephone($addressData['fax'])
                ->setData('landline', $addressData['telephone'])
                ->setStreet($addressData['street_array']);

$this->customerAddressRepository->save($address);
```

As you can see, I'm using 'setData' for landline attribute. If I use: setLandline, the following error is thrown:

```
Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address::setLandline()
```

How can I save this attribute programmatically? What am I doing wrong? I'm using Magento 2.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using this

```
->setCustomAttribute('landline', $addressData['telephone']);
```

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I've looked for this answer in google and stackoverflow before asking and I didn't find anything. Hope this helps other people too!